# Javascript: Check to see if multiple array values are the same (order matters)

Tags: javascript, arrays

If I have two arrays, lets say

```
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

I would like to check if to see if the number 1 appears three times in order so that the first array would return true and the second would return false.

I'm not really sure how to accomplish this (since order matters).

Comment: iterate through the array, and increment a counter when you see a 1 and clear it when you see 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a counter to see if values of `1` are sequential.

```js
function containsSequence(arr, val, max) {
      var count = 0;

      for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] === val) {
          counter++; // increment the counter by 1
        }
        else {
          counter = 0; // reset counter
        }
    
        // our counter met our maximum
        if (counter >= max) {
          return true;
        }
      }

      // if we get this far, there was no sequence
      return false;
    }
    
    console.log(containsSequence([0,0,1,1,1,0], 1, 3)); // true
    console.log(containsSequence([0,1,0,1,0,1], 1, 3)); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

- Loop through the array,
- each time take three elements from the array -if possible- starting from the element `i`
- Check if those three elements equals one

---

```js
function check(arr){
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
        if(arr[i] && arr[i+1] && arr[i+2])
            if(arr[i] == arr[i+1] == arr[i+2] == 1)
                return true;
    return false;
}
console.log(check([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0]));
console.log(check([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]));
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution using [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) - tracks the count and index to test the array for consecutive numbers:

```js
var test1 = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0];
var test2 = [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1];

function test(arr, num, max) {
  return arr.some(function(element, index) {
    if(element == num) {
       this.prevIndex = (this.prevIndex + 1) || index;
       this.count = this.count || 0;
       if(this.prevIndex == index) 
         this.count++;
       else
         this.count = 1;
       if(this.count == max) return true;
    }
  }, Object.create(null));
}

console.log(test(test1, 1, 3));
console.log(test(test2, 1, 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `counter` to check if the desired value `val` is repeated sequentially a `limit` of times:

```js
function checkLimit(arr, val, limit) {
  var counter = 0;
  for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
    counter = (arr[i] === val) ? ++counter : 0;
    if (counter === limit) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
console.log(checkLimit([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0], 1, 3)); // true
console.log(checkLimit([0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], 1, 3)); // false
```

Answer (score -2):

Check this code snippet

```
var arr1=[0,0,1,1,1,0]
var arr2=[0,1,0,1,0,1]

console.log(checkThreeOnes(arr1));

console.log(checkThreeOnes(arr2));
function checkThreeOnes(numbers){
  var i=0;
  var j=numbers.length;
  var oneCount=1;
  for(var i=0;i<j;){

       if(numbers[i]==numbers[i+1]){
           oneCount++;
           if(oneCount==3)
            return true;
       }
    else
      oneCount=1;
      i++;

  }
  return false;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: When you get to the last element of the array this is going to explode: "numbers[i+1]". Also, what happens if there are three 0s? How is the for-loop's index getting incremented after two consecutive numbers in the array turn out to be the same?